# Annotate a vector using GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

I start with the following "annotation function":

```
 AnnotatedArrow[p_, q_, label_] := {Arrowheads[{{.1, .5, 
     Graphics[Inset[Style[label, Medium], {Center, Top}]]}, {.1, 1}}],
   Arrow[{p, q}]}
```

and use it to annotate the arrow (vector) in the following example:

```
 Graphics[{AnnotatedArrow[{0, 0}, {0, -1}, "Radius = 60 miles"], Circle[]}]
```

Similarly; I want to be able to annotate a vector using GeoGraph.  The center of a circle is given by:

```
 center = GeoPosition[{30.731064, -86.474072}]
```

The radius of the circle has length 60 miles:

```
 radius = Interpreter["Quantity"]["60 miles"]
```

Next; Alpha is the angle of rotation for the arrow-vector (which has its tail at the center but, the tip is pointing North by default; i.e., Alpha = 0 ). I want the vector pointing South, so; the vector must be rotated 180 degrees clockwise; i.e. Alpha = 180:

```
 \[Alpha] = Interpreter["Quantity"]["180 degree"]

 arrowtiplocation = GeoDestination[center, GeoDisplacement[{radius, \[Alpha]}]]

 GeoGraphics[Arrow[GeoPosition[{center, arrowtiplocation}]]]
```

I verify that the vector has a magnitude of 60 miles as follows:

```
 GeoDistance[center, arrowtiplocation]
```

Finally; when I attempt to annotate the vector using my annotation function above; I get the following picture:

```
GeoGraphics[{AnnotatedArrow[center, arrowtiplocation, "Radius = 60 miles"], GeoCircle[center, radius]}]
```

The vector shows but, the annotation does not carry through.  Are there easier ways to annotate a vector within GeoGraph?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 pointtodisplacetitle = GeoPosition[{30.65, -86.35}]

 GeoGraphics[
   {GeoCircle[center, radius], 
    Arrow[GeoPosition[{center, arrowtiplocation}]], 
    Inset[Style["Radius = 60 miles", 20], 
    pointtodisplacetitle, 
    Right, 
    Automatic, 
   {0, 1}]}]
```